# Rotating UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to rotate a UIImageView, and I am using this code:

```
-(IBAction)rotateImageView:(id)sender{
 photoView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI); //rotation in radians
}
```

The code works. when I press the button, the image rotates 180 degrees, but if I press it again it doesn't rotate back to its original position, but it stays still. why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are applying the same transform to the view again, without taking into account any existing transform.

Try this:

`photoView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(photoView.transform,M_PI);`

Comment: for some reason doing this: -(IBAction)rotateImageView:(id)sender{
 CGAffineTransformRotate(photoView.transform, M_PI);
} doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rotate the imageView from the current rotation to make it original

use this code

```
CGAffineTransformRotate(photoView.transform, M_PI);
```